# Docker Container of an entire LINUX OS

Tags: docker, debian, aws, container

Can a Docker container be built from an entire LINUX machine?  We have an AWS AMI of the OS.  Can that be used instead of an application?

Comment: Is the goal to have an OS in a container (to do many things) or a collection of packages in a container (to do focus on one thing)?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: If you're looking for a "VM-like" container, LXC/LXD might be a better choice.

Comment: It is a collection of packages and specifically an application we developed, not just a LINUX container.  There are many of those on docker.com.  I'm asking if we can containerize our custom instalation of LINUX + our application without installing our application in a preconfigured linux OS container.  This would avoid a lot of steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can build your own "base OS" using tar | Docker.  This is different from including all the dependencies and leaving out the kernel as is usually done in Docker, on purpose.  The Client wasn't worried about size of image, they wanted a complete package of the OS.  I know it would be more efficient to strip everything out that wasn't needed, but not our Use Case.

Comment: Thank you for seeing this aging question to a resolution. You are able to [mark this as the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/352329) if you wish. You haven't yet taken the AskUbuntu [tour]; please do.